# Bionicle sets with staffs identification

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, bionicle

I bought this series of 4 lovely small monsters/gods at a garage sale.

Body, arms, legs and hands are made of Technic and are studless.

Help me to identify:

- if they are part of an official set of The LEGO Group, and which one?
- which are parts such as the masks, the foots (which are also used as
  the support of the masks), the weapons?

[image: The 4 monsters/gods]

**Update:** This might be from the Bionicle / Turaga ([BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=273.676)) or similar range. So any links to introduction to this series would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are indeed Bionicles

Green: [1418: Matau](https://brickset.com/sets/1418-1/Matau)

Blue: [8543-1: Nokama](https://brickset.com/sets/8543-1/Nokama)

Red: [8540: Vakama](https://brickset.com/sets/8540-1/Vakama)

I think the last one is [8542: Onewa](https://brickset.com/sets/8542-1/Onewa), with the mask of [8545-1: Whenua](https://brickset.com/sets/8545-1/Whenua)

more information on the [Bionicles theme](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/BIONICLE) and the [story line](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/BIONICLE_storyline) from [Brickipedia](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/LEGO_Wiki)
the [Turega](https://bionicle.fandom.com/wiki/Turaga) have a page on the [Bionicle Wiki](https://bionicle.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bionicle_Wiki)